# Eliminating the Need For Hidden Input Fields

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, mootools, hidden-field

I have several hidden input fields used to hold coordinates calculated by javascript. The purpose of these fields is to pass the coordinates when the form is submitted. I am using an AJAX request through MooTools. Is there a simple way to eliminate the hidden input fields and append them to the $_POST data being sent through the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. if very much depends on the way your form data is defined / how it is sent. for example:

`new Request({ data: $("formid") }).send();` will serialise the form and send all form fields through. what you can do is move the hidden fields into the form before submit so it will include them also (via `$("formid").adopt(el1, el2, ... eln);` where els are your hiddens - or a collection you have done like `$$("input[type=hidden]")`.

if you compose the data object manually then just add them to it with a key, its just a hash table of key->value pairs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is exactly what I ended up doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MooTools, but my experience with Prototype, jQuery, and raw Javascript patterns is that Javascript-based POSTs are done with a <form> element created on the fly. Appending POST data is done by adding hidden input fields to that form element, and then the form is submitted.

What's the reason you don't want to use hidden input fields? Does the job for me...

Comment: I'm just curious about other ways of doing it. It's not a requirement of any kind.